# How to add validation in migration file (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I'm trying to add validation at the database level. For the model file it was no problem but now for the migration file, I just don't get how to do this. I am using SQLite for development (following Hartl's tutorial but adapting the instructions for my own app).

I have the two following migration files:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.string  :email,           null: false
      t.string  :email_confirm,   null: false
      t.string  :username,        null: false
      t.text    :bio
      t.string  :location,        null: false
      t.boolean :activated,       default: false
      t.datetime :activated_at

      t.timestamps             null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and:

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmailAndUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users,  :email,         unique: true
    add_index :users,  :username,      unique: true
  end
end
```

But the validations do not end up in schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150410200022) do

  create_table "Users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "email_confirm"
    t.string   "username"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.string   "location"
    t.boolean  "activated"
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true

end
```

So `null:false` and `default:false` are not in schema.rb and apparantly Rails is not implementing these validations. How should I implement these validations in the migration file?

I've also tried using `change_column_null` and `change_column_default` instead but with the same result/schema.rb.

Comment: Have you been editing migrations after running them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does let you provide `null` and `default` options to columns in migrations.

After editing the user migration file, have you rerun it?

You can do a `rake db:rollback` followed by a `rake db:migrate`

If you had run `CreateUsers` and `AddIndexToUsersEmailAndUsername` for last, You should do a rollback with two steps like `rake db:rollback STEP=2`

Comment: I have done `bundle exec rake db:reset` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. I guess that's even better than a rollback...? so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate VERSION=0` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. This worked! Schema.rb does now indeed include the `null`  and `default` options.